# How are traditional features handled in an api-driven website?

Tags: php, api

I come from the old PHP ways of mixing front and back. And I want to jump into all this fancy react, angular, etc... world. But I have no clue in how the traditional logic is handled.

Okay yeah I can grab a few posts from a headless WordPress or use the modern Strapi CMS to make content in the backend and then consume it from the front.

But, what if I have a contact form and I want the backend to send an email with the contact form data? I used to collect the data with PHP and send the email...

INTUITION says: just create a backend endpoint where I will do a Javascript POST with the fetch API and just throw in the form data and then do my stuff in the backend? Is that how it works? SO like... EVERYTHING is made in an API way?

And from people who know both sides of the coin. Is this modern approach really better? Like, so much better that I should throw away my old mental scheme of doing things?

Thanks for your wisdom. I am very ignorant regarding this topic.

Comment: Yes a good way to go is to completely split your backend from your front end. Expose all backend logic that the front end will need via API's and use javascript to talk to that api

Comment: If you think about it, the difference between something like a contact form using "old" style where you post a form to a "PHP endpoint" vs letting JS posting data to an "API endpoint" (which will also just be a "PHP endpoint" when you think of it) isn't really that different. It's still just a HTTP POST request with the data. And instead of returning the response as a HTML page, you return it as JSON instead. It's basically the same thing, you usually just use different formats for the data and the response.

Comment: No, the 'new way' not at all better. I'm saying this as someone who's been doing web dev for nearly 20 years, and currently do a lot of SPA, api-driven apps. Do the simplest thing that solves your problem. It's easy to get the impression that the 'new way is better', but a big reason for this is most junior devs now *start* with API + React, and they simply don't know better.

Comment: That said there's reasons why it's nice/helpful sometimes, for example when you have multiple consumers of the API. But requirements should drive the technology goal, and the complex thing should probably not be people's defaults anyway.

Comment: Just make sure you read up on how to handle security, like [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) tokens and such in a good way (which might not be as straight forward as in the "old" way), and also not to allow anyone to access your API's (unless it's ok for people to use your data in their applications).

Comment: @Evert It's strange because you kind of "suggest" that the "old" way is not so old after all. I got a lot of "hate" from modern people and it's what pushed me to think that I am just doing it wrong. But yeah, you don't seem to hate the "old" way so much, and that puts some relief on me. Will keep learning about it anyways. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question:

> How are traditional features handled in an api-driven website?

In an api-driven website, every "feature" is handled via an API.

You can think of an API as a **bridge** between the back and the front of your site.

It's more or less the same than the "traditional" way, just separating functionality from presentation and using a messenger that brings information from one side to the other and viceversa.

Not only will you be able to work in a more organized way, by **separating concerns**. But you will also be able to reuse the same backend from different frontends, like from a normal online website, an Android app, an iOS app, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The "old" way of developing web application has one big limitation: The backend logic is mixed with the frontend logic which makes it hard to move to new technologies. At least that's what I understand by "old" php. I am currently working on a project which was written in stone old IBM Notes stuff (not XPages) where all the backend logic is mixed up completely with the frontend logic. Making it extremely hard to move it to a new frontend technology (Angular) and to actually strip out the backend logic and implement it in a new REST API.

Basically, the abstraction you usually do nowadays allows you to switch technologies easily and allow you to develop e.g. apps by using the already existing API. Another advantage is that you can develop front- and backend individually and don't have to wait for each other (by using mocks etc.).

For your example: Basically your frontend just sends API calls (e.g. sendMail) and works with the individual responses.

It's mostly a matter of taste - you can do both approaches. And one could argue that JSF is still somehow the same, although it forces a separation between backend and frontend logic while still being one monolithic project.

I personally prefer the "new" way for new applications. For (very) small application, I may still use the old approach since it's not worth the time to abstract and setup two projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to upvote this one but I have not enough reputation. I accepted the other one just because it was very clear, but this information is helpful too! :)

Comment: I would say that it completely depends on how the application is built. Even the "old" way could be very well separated, code wise.